# Getting particular words in text file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file contains "A 0001 1212 00 @@ word" in this format, I wanted to print when Accessing word then only 0001 1212 part has to show along with 00 also has to show dynamically

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?  I am not really following your format.

```
f=open(filepath, 'r')
hold = f.read()
#hold now = 'A 0001 1212 00 @@ word'
holdout = hold.replace( '@@ word','')
#holdout now = 'A 0001 1212 00 '
#the replace call uses this format 
#string.replace('what it is looking for', 'what it is going to be')
```

Is this what you want?  Is there only one line in this file?

Comment: only textfile contains "A 0001 1212 00 @@ word" ok when I tried to fetch "word" then 0001 1212 text should show in output file

Comment: could you import the data as a string and then do string - 'word'.  Is this what you are looking for in your output?  Could you make a before formatting and desired post formatting example?  (you should edit this into your question).

Comment: @deadstump: I'm pretty sure you can't subtract strings like that.